# Pullout the data from table using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, output

In the below SQL Server table, I want the values to take it into new table and the scenario is:
until the **each** User_ID reaches the value '1'(including this iteration) the loop should continue. Once if the User_ID reaches '1' from the next iteration the loop should quit and start with next User_ID and so on.

```
User_ID | Value
---------------    
**167    | 0**
**167    | 0**
175    | 0
175    | 0
175    | 0
175    | 1
**167    | 1**
**167    | 0**
175    | 0
188    | 0
188    | 1
**167    | 1**
188    | 0
216    | 1
188    | 1
217    | 0
```

The output should be like this:

```
User_ID | Value
-----------------    
**167    | 0**
**167    | 0**
**167    | 1**
175    | 0
175    | 0
175    | 0
175    | 1
188    | 0
188    | 1
216    | 1
217    | 0
```

Comment: Show us your SQL statement .

Comment: What are the '**' for? Are they in the data?

Comment: How is the order determined? How do you know that a certain row comes before another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this...

```
create table #outTable
(
    rowID   int identity(1, 1),
    User_ID varchar(10),
    value   varchar(10),
)
insert into #outTable(User_ID, value)
select USER_ID, value
from   UserTable

declare @User_ID varchar(10),
        @value   varchar(10);
declare @break   int;    
declare @cnt int;
declare curUser cursor for select distinct User_ID from #outTable
open curUser 
fetch next from curUser into @user_ID
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin
     SET @cnt = 0;
     SELECT @cnt = MIN(rowID)
     FROM   #outTable
     WHERE  User_ID = @user_ID AND value LIKE '1%';

     IF (@cnt > 1)
     BEGIN
        DELETE FROM #outTable WHERE User_ID = @user_ID AND rowID > @cnt;
     END 
     fetch next from curUser into @user_ID
end
close curUser;
deallocate curUser;

select * from #outTable order by USER_ID;
DROP TABLE #outTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT *, 
       Row_number () 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY USER_ID 
           ORDER BY Newid()) RN 
INTO   #DATA 
FROM   TABLE1; 

WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                VALUE AS sumVal 
         FROM   #DATA 
         WHERE  RN = 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t1.USER_ID, 
                T1.VALUE, 
                T1.RN, 
                T1.VALUE + ( T2.SUMVAL * 2 ) AS SumVal 
         FROM   #DATA T1 
                INNER JOIN CTE T2 
                        ON T1.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID 
                           AND T1.RN = T2.RN + 1) 
SELECT USER_ID, 
       VALUE 
FROM   CTE 
WHERE  SUMVAL <= 1
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56733/37).

You will notice that you get different results each time!
Since there is nothing in the table itself that defines the order, I had to add a "random" order to the table.